# htaccess redirect non-www to www without losing script and query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect from this:

```
http://example.com/admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=e687040d4b0f5f42a4eab8951a3b57b4
```

To this:

```
http://www.example.com/admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=e687040d4b0f5f42a4eab8951a3b57b4
```

My htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/%{THE_REQUEST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it redirects me to this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?route=common/home&token=e687040d4b0f5f42a4eab8951a3b57b4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```